# Cannot install Docker on Debian Jessie

Tags: docker, debian, docker-engine

Despite trying both the official installation mechanism using the new apt repo described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/), as well as the `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` route, I still get `E: Unable to locate package docker-engine` from APT when I try to `apt-get install docker-engine`.

My versions are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux blah 4.5.5-x86_64-linode69 #3 SMP Fri May 20 15:25:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lsb_release -c
Codename:       jessie

$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.5

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stable main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

The only file in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is `docker.list` which contains:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main
```

`apt-cache policy docker-engine` doesn't find it either:

```
apt-cache policy docker-engine
N: Unable to locate package docker-engine
```

How might I resolve this?

Comment: did you already perform an apt-get update before?

Comment: Yep, and after. Several times too.

Comment: Are you using debian 8.0 jessie 64-bit? + if yes: what's the content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list

Comment: backports.list doesn't exist at that location. How do I confirm which architecture version of debian I have installed? I suspect it could be 32bit from memory...

Comment: I see x86_64 as output of your uname -r so your using 64 bit which is fine and supported by docker. When you don't have that file you have to create it manually. Check the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your `sources.list` and change the following line from:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

to

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Update and install [docker](https://wiki.debian.org/Docker):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install docker.io
```

**Edit**

To install a specific version of `docker-engine` download the `.deb` package from [here](https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/), e,g the latest one is `docker-engine_1.9.1-0~jessie_amd64.deb`:

```
wget https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/docker-engine_1.9.1-0~jessie_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
dpkg -i docker-engine_1.9.1-0~jessie_amd64.deb
```

Maybe you will get an error , to fix it run:

```
apt-get -f install
dpkg -i docker-engine_1.9.1-0~jessie_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This isn't the latest docker version. Why can't I install `docker-engine`? `docker.io` installed this way is at version 1.6.2, that's [_really_ old](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#162-2015-05-13)!

Comment: I think we've found my problem: it claims incorrect architecture as the system is i386 but the deb's amd64 (despite uname reporting x86_64)...could this be why it's not downloading via apt?

Comment: Exactly docker is only supported by 64 bit systems as described here :https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/

Comment: Which will explain why it doesn't download via apt (regardless of arch expression in the deb line in the docker.list) -- i386 isn't available. Uname reports x86_64 but IIRC I installed Debian 32bit originally as the VM only had 3GB of RAM...

Answer (score 4):

Your `dpkg` architecture is probably using `32bit`. You can check this using:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

Fix it by adding `amd64` as a foreign architecture:

```
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Update your package lists and check for `docker-engine`:

```
apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-engine
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Answer (score 2):

Login as root user

```
$ sudo su
```

Create this file if it does not exist:

```
# vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

Add this as content of your `backports.list`

```
 deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
```

Now perform your apt-get update

```
# apt-get update
```

Install the CA certificates

```
 # apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Add the new GPG key

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```

Now open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` (or create when it does not exist)

```
# vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Add as content:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main
```

Perform again your update:

```
# apt-get update
```

Verify that APT is pulling from the right repository.

```
# apt-cache policy docker-engine
```

Update again

```
# sudo apt-get update
```

Install Docker:

```
# sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Start the docker daemon.

```
# sudo service docker start
```

Verify docker is installed correctly.

```
# sudo docker run hello-world
```

Comment: Added backports but docker-engine still can't be found.

Comment: did you perform every step, also with the certs

Comment: Yep. Certs were already installed (even prior to me doing that from the official Docker installation instructions). Most of what you recommend here is just what the docker install does, minus the jessie-backports stuff. No luck :(

Comment: I would try to reinstall/redo the certificates stuff.

Comment: Purged `apt-transport-https` and `ca-certificates`, then did an `apt-get update` and `apt-cache policy docker-engine`. No dice :( I noticed I had `wheezy-backports` in my apt sources.list. I commented that out, `apt-get update`, no luck. I then realised I'm downloading `i386` arch when doing `apt-get update`...Could this be an issue? I've added `[arch=i386] ` to the docker.list file but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I faced the same problem and recently found a script automated the docker installation process in debian 8. You could see the snippet here (https://gist.github.com/frgomes/a6f889583860f5b330c06c8b46fa0f42). Credit goes to the original script creator.

I add this on line 4 to removed older versions of Docker if it were existed:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine
```

and few line on line 7:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common -y
```

Then as superuser:

```
# chmod +x ./install-docker.sh
# sudo ./install-docker.sh
```

And you get latest docker instead of v 1.5-1:

```
# docker --version
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```